# C# List Gives ListName.Add does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, list, constructor

```
namespace Inventory_Management_System
{
    class InHousePart : Part
    {
        public int machineId { get; set; }

        public InHousePart(string partName, int invLvl, double partPrice, int invMax, int invMin, int macId)
        : base(partName,invLvl,partPrice,invMax,invMin)
        {
            machineId = macId;
        }


        public List<InHousePart> InHouseList = new List<InHousePart>();
        InHouseList.Add("Chain", 8, 12.99, 2, 20, 125);
        InHouseList.Add("Tire", 6, 26.77, 4, 24, 188);
        InHouseList.Add("Wheel", 8, 22.50, 4, 12,215);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to create a list of parts. I would like to do this using my constructor however when I try to create the list Visual Studio is telling me The name InHouseList.Add does not exist in this context. I know I must be missing something I'm just not sure what it is. I tried creating parts and then using those parts to populate a list. IE Create InHousePart chain = new InHousePart(...); I tried changing the List to a string or an int with no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add  with object initialize like bellow

```
  public List<InHousePart> InHouseList { get; set; } = new List<InHousePart> 
    {
        new InHousePart("Chain", 8, 12.99, 2, 20, 125), 
        new InHousePart("Tire", 6, 26.77, 4, 24, 188), 
        new InHousePart("Wheel", 8, 22.50, 4, 12, 215), 

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create, InHousePart objects and add those to the List

```
    InHousePart ihp = new InHousePart(parameters);
    InHouseList.Add(ihp);
    ihp = new InHousePart( 2nd set of parameters);
    InHouseList.Add(ihp);
```

Other than that, what you are trying to do it a bit confusing and please provide with more info as the base class, and what is your final goal.

Just a side note: other than for testing, it is very rare that you hard code values inside a class itself. Better way is to call the class with appropriate parameters in main() method

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I did end up moving those to my Program.cs instead of leaving them in class file.